# Is it ok to ask a question where you've found a solution but don't know why something was behaving the way it was?

Tags: discussion

Is it acceptable to ask a question where you have found a solution, but you don't know what the root cause of the problem was or why some bug was causing something to act some way?

I'm wondering this because I recently found an easy solution to a problem where (believe it or not) something was working on Internet Explorer and not on Chrome (and it wasn't malware)!

I still don't know why Chrome was/does behave the way it did in my situation but I know *how* to fix it. If I were on Stack Overflow would it be ok to post my code, my solution, and ask why I was getting this behavior or is this unacceptable?

Comment: You are going to come across more instances of something working on IE but not Chrome from now on. I guarantee it.

Comment: This is a good question to ask - because unpicking what's going on and understanding it is exactly the sort of thing that's useful to future users of the site.

Comment: And then edit a link into this question so we can see it.

Comment: @AbraCadaver http://stackoverflow.com/q/32637062/1896169

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are questions about why a solution worked acceptable?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/406104/are-questions-about-why-a-solution-worked-acceptable)

Comment: @HongOoi That linked question is already a duplicate of this one...

Comment: @Hong Ooi: Whoa, are you a time traveler?!

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Yes, it's entirely acceptable to ask what was causing a problem, or why a piece of code solves it the way it does.

Be sure to include not just the problem description and [code to reproduce it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), but also the code that solves the problem, in your question, since the question revolves around precisely that code. Just keep in mind that [some people don't read and will try to answer with a solution anyway even though you've already found one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/246665/why-do-people-ask-why-questions-with-the-why-capitalized-and-excessively-for/246666#246666).

Comment: I don't see most of these kind of questions coming out well written though. Your answer needs to be taken with a grain of salt

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ: Yeah, we'll have to see what the OP comes up with.

Comment: You could probably flesh out with some pointers to the help center ;-).

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ: I guess certain things do need to be spelled out every time...

Comment: Thank you for the pointers (and the pointers on my question itself @BoltClock. The question is posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32637062/why-does-this-dropdown-list-for-sorting-work-in-internet-explorer-but-not-in-chr

Comment: @MaxPoshusta C#/Razor code in the post was not related to the question at all and caused somewhat random answer (which did not answer your question)... You should have stick with just JS/HTML (also at the end question is "why IE allows invalid Url to be used as `window.location` " which would be on the edge of "too broad")

Comment: @Alexei Levenkov: I imagine it'd be a bit difficult to reduce their existing code into a test case absent of all Razor code though. I can see why the use of Html.Raw could have masked the issue somewhat. It was my idea that the OP add the [razor] tag to their question, and for that I apologize for the confusion.

Comment: @BoltClock I hope it not too hard  - the sample is one line of JavaScript - since it did not work properly I'd expect OP stepped through with JS debugger and knew exact value of the string generated by C#/Razor. Adding third language to the mix made actual question harder to spot - IE vs. Chrome. Based on OP's questions they have some knowledge of HTML, but indeed if OP does not know how to debug JavaScript or how to check HTML produced by server the question should be very different...

Comment: @Alexei Levenkov: Fair enough.